# Why is [itextsharp] mapped to [itext]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I tried to add [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) as a tag to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993783/how-to-import-bookmark-from-xml-to-existing-pdf), but unfortunately only the [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) tag got added. Why is [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) mapped to [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info) it says:

> iText is available in Java as well as in C#.

and at the right side of that page you see the tag synonyms where [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextsharp) is one of them.
[image]

When a library has no major differences between platforms there is no real need to distinguish the two. By having one tag you probably have more chance to get your question answered as both C# and Java users can chime in. For the few questions that only pertain to C# it is not worth to have a separate tag.

Comment: Thanks. Let See that my question get answerable or not based on this tag. Hope for the best

Comment: Yes. This is *exactly* the reason. I work at iText, and I suggested that change on the iText slack on June 14th. The change was made on June 16th and approved by votes on June 17th.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thanks, you might consider to change the excerpt a bit as it now only mentions Java.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I made the edit, it's now waiting for peer review.

Comment: I just got notified that the change was approved.

Comment: Yep, magic happens sometimes ... ;)

Comment: By the way, this is a good question AND a good answer. *clickety-click*